# Lazy loading variables in templates

Tags: php, templates, lazy-loading

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
function load_template($script, $args){
  extract($args);
  require __DIR__ . '/templates/' . $script;
}
```

In my controller code:

```
// if home page was requested
load_template('home.php', array(
  'title'   => get_title(),
  'content' => get_content(),
  ...
));
```

The template is just a PHP script like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> <?php echo $title; ?> </titlee>
...
```

I was wondering if it's possible to lazy load these variables somehow, so I don't actually run `get_title()` or `get_content()` until the template specifically requests the variable.

Could this be possible, without creating a template parser thingy? I'd really like to stick with simple .php scripts and html as templates.

---

In short, what I'm asking is if it's possible to auto-assign a value to a variable only when it's first requested.

```
$var = func();  // this should not run

if($var){       // now the code above should run:)
  echo $var;   // <- the value that was just assigned (don't run func() again)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you do not wish to change your template to extract the variables, you can create for example an array that would know which variables each template needs.

You may consider a function (let's name it `caller`) into which you pass all parameters and the template name. The `caller` could choose which variables are required. This idea is like a factory class in oop.

I think there is no other way, but...

While inserting a template and use unexistent variable, a warning will be shown. You can make PHP to throw exceptions in warnings and then in `try ... catch` block parse it. I think it's too complicated and not worth effort.

**EDIT**

The third idea is to create objects instead of arrays. The object would keep all your `$args` variable. In your template just change `<?php echo $title; ?>` to `<?php echo $argument_object->getTitle(); ?>`, and code the `getTitle()` method. The `getTitle()`, as a method not a function, would then be run only on request.